# Got a inconvenient Inserting values into VS with SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I'm doing a project doing an Inventory inserting images to SQL Server 2016 using VS 2017 and I followed some forums to inserting data values from VS. When I execute my app, it causes a problem.

Here is the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOvmA.jpg

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial 
    Catalog=MyInventory;Integrated Security=True");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void butSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CN.Open();
        int i = 0;

        SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO  MyInventory (ID, Nombre, Aula, Departamento, Especificacion) VALUES ('" + 
        txtID.Text+ "','" + txtNombre.Text + "','" + txtAula.Text + "','" + 
        txtDep.Text + "',@Especificacion)",CN);

        MemoryStream STREAM = new MemoryStream();
        PB.Image.Save(STREAM, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[ ] PIC = STREAM.ToArray();

        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Especificacion", PIC);

        i = CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (1 > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Equipo registrado" + i);
        }

        CN.Close();
    }

    private void butOpenPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OFD.Filter = "JPG | *.jpg";
        DialogResult RES = OFD.ShowDialog();

        if (RES == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            PB.Image = Image.FromFile(OFD.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for not upload an image of my table on SQL Server 2016:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xabEp.jpg

Comment: It's hard to be sure without knowing your schema but it sounds like you are trying to insert a value in to the ID field which should not be provided as it will be automatically generated. So remove ID and it's corresponding value.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Also, from the error message, it seems you're trying to insert the identity value into the table - **don't do that!** Do **NOT** provide a value for that column which is defined as `int identity` - SQL Server will automatically provide a value of its own.

Comment: Ahh thnx bro I solved It